# What SATA does an early 2011 MacBook Pro has?

Tags: ssd, sata

I want to get a SSD for my early 2011 MacBook Pro 15" and I'm not sure what SATA interface it has and what it would be the best price/performance blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to use a MBP 15" early 2011 and it has a SATA 3 (6.0 Gbit/s) interface.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to give a general price recommendation for an SSD because the performance of SSDs varies quite noticeably depending on the manufacturer. Instead, I try to follow recommendations that people give who have used the specific SSD model for some time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm considering preordering the new Intel 330 model but as you may expect, I cannot get any existing reviews on it yet.